# SumIf varying criteria

Tags: excel

Is there a way to use the SumIf function on excel where the range criteria is not very specific? I have a column with variations of the same criteria, its a company's name but in my raw data the order of the words varies. I have one consistent and identifiable word I want to use in my formula as the criteria, but I'm not sure how to incorporate this to include every variation of the name - I keep getting error's

Comment: Can you give a sample of what the different values look like? Sounds like the wildcard character `*` might solve the problem.

Comment: For example, one would be "ABC & Co." and the other would be "Company of ABC". I want to be able to use ABC as the criteria

Comment: In that case, try using `*ABC*` as your criterion.

Comment: Use wildcard with criteria.

Comment: Thanks it worked!